# Asking for a number in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, error-handling

Is it good way of asking for a number? Should that function return 0 if there is an error?

```
private int getNumberDialog(String message) {
            try {
                String resultInString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
                int result = Integer.parseInt(resultInString);
                return result;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't gave a number");
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code from where you call this method. It is difficult to answer in a good way without seeing that code.

Comment: I just use it by: 
`public void playForMeNrTimes() {
  int howManyTimes = getNumberDialog("How many times?");
  game.playForMeNrTimes(howManyTimes);
 }`
I just want to know if handling an exception this way is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using "special return values" in code for when errors occur. It should be up to the calling code how to handle the situation.

I would let the `getNumberDialog` utility function re-throw the exception:

```
private int getNumberDialog(String message) throws NumberFormatException {
    String resultInString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
    int result = Integer.parseInt(resultInString);
    return result;
}
```

And in your usage code, you catch the exception:

```
try {
    int times = getNumberDialog("How many times?");
    game.playForMeNrTimes(times);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't gave a number");
}
```

The key here is that the utility-function `getNumberDialog` doesn't know about any context. It doesn't know how the returned value will be used, so how can it possibly decide on a default value to use in the case of an error?

Comment: Thanks, If I would also like to check if number is possitive, should it be done in getNumberDialog method or no?

Comment: @siema Ask yourself the question: Do you ***always*** want to make sure the number is positive? You probably don't want to do it inside that method.